# How to prevent R from rounding seconds

Tags: r

I have a csv file containing timed data... now when i read it using `read.csv.raw()` it reads the time col as character--->

```
"19:56:05.938836" "19:56:06.269024" "19:56:06.868525" "19:56:15.080690" "19:56:15.422007" "19:56:16.132036"
```

now to convert it into a time object i am using `chron::times()`, which gives time object as-->

```
19:56:06 19:56:06 19:56:07 19:56:15 19:56:15 19:56:16
```

Clearly it is rounding the time... which i don't want, as i need millisecond resolution.
Is there a way to convert that char time vector to time object without any rounding off?

update---->

so i want it to be(I need)-

```
19:56:05 19:56:06 19:56:06 19:56:15 19:56:15 19:56:16
```

as time object so that I can compare hours, mins etc...

Comment: maybe you don't need the hours and minutes if you need the ms ?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper please see the updated question. sorry for the ambiguity...

Comment: Your update appears slightly confusing. Do you mean you want to maintain the original precision in milliseconds, or do you mean you want it to always round DOWN to the nearest second?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `lubridate` package to maintain the full precision of your data.

```
times <-
  c(
    "19:56:05.938836",
    "19:56:06.269024",
    "19:56:06.868525",
    "19:56:15.080690",
    "19:56:15.422007",
    "19:56:16.132036"
  )

hms(times)
# [1] "19H 56M 5.938836S"  "19H 56M 6.269024S"  "19H 56M 6.868525S"  "19H 56M 15.08069S"
# [5] "19H 56M 15.422007S" "19H 56M 16.132036S"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can strip off the 'milliseconds' from your string and convert that to a 'time' object as follows:

```
> chron::times(sub("\\..*", "", "19:56:05.938836"))
[1] 19:56:05
```